# what are peer to peer routing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, routes, p2p

After several unsuccessful attempts to use JXTA api, i have decided to roll out my own peer to peer api. Am new to network programming in java. My greatest obstacle now is how to enable each peer in a network or internet detect each other. I think thats the function of a P2P routing algorithm, are there existing P2P routing algorithm api to use and can someone please tell me the best algorithm among CHORD, CAN, PASTRY etc and how i can use its Distributed Hash Table to enable each peer detect other peers on same LAN, WLAN and/or Internet. Thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Something important: LAN host detection is generally much simpler, since you can broadcast messages at least within the same segment. Peer detection over WAN or the Internet is a completely different story...

Comment: can   you   give   me  tips   or   links   on   how   to   detect   peers   on   a lan.   Any   idea   about  doing   same   for  WAN/Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a centralized infrastructure where a current list of clients is updated in a regular fashion. When you have downloaded the list the clients can update the list automatically without the host.

Comment: By centralised, i guess you mean an ip address that each peer connects to and it records the peer address and the peer can now download list of other peers and can now communicate directly with these peers? thanks for the suggestion, will consider that, but any idea on decentralised peer detection?

Comment: I don't think you can fully automated a dht. A least you want to have some control about the peers? The problem is also if write a crawler it would look very long to find another peer and maybe it's just easier to register a static ip to bootstrap the dth. When you want peer detection you need also content detection because it doesn't make sense to detect any peer possible?